# вычисление семантическое сходство между парами (сущ, сущ)

Tags: java, алгоритм, nlp

Есть ли алгоритм, который говорит о семантическом сходстве двух фраз?

Comment: Можно примеры входных/выходных данных для такого алгоритма?

Comment: В виде пар у меня медицинские слова. Пример: болезнь-рак, грипп-лечение итд

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться такой структурой как: `word2vec`.

Если требуется семантическая схожесть двух слов `w1` и `w2`, то просто надо измерить `similarity(w1, w2)`. В случае фраз можно измерить близость между суммами векторов каждой из фраз: `similarity(sum(phrase1), sum(phrase2))`.

По идее, функция `similarity` должна быть реализована в пакетах, предоставляющих `word2vec`. А так, довольно часто функцией схожести может послужить косинусная метрика или расстояние Евклида.